# "No resolved dependencies found when searching for the jacoco version." After cloning an app from Git and trying to Sync Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github

I had recently Cloned https://github.com/GauravChaddha1996/Bluetooth-Remote-Camera-App and did everything from updating my android studio to downloading tools and SDKs. I am fairly new to app development and would like to find a solution to how I can build and run the application as I plan on using it as a base for my upcoming project. [Error on syncing Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmBqy.png)

Answer (score 0):

This should be something to do with the dependency you're using (jacoco). In the github link you provided, in the `gradle.build` file, I dont see any dependencies specified. You should check that. Here is a reference on integrate JaCoCo to android projects

https://blog.mindorks.com/generate-global-code-coverage-report-in-android-development-using-jacoco-plugin